# How do we sort core data fetch results based on a BOOL

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a flag in my core data model (isDaySpecial), while I fetch my desired, I want to get the sorted based on **isDaySpecial** flag. All records with **isDaySpecial = 1** should come top in the list.

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"isDaySpecial" ascending:YES];

Comment: @Tim007 - for true values on top, should be `ascending:NO`

Comment: @sschale - thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @Tim007's answer, you will use an `NSSortDescriptor` to order your data. Assuming you've fetched your data and it is an array, you will pass

```
sortedArray = dataArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "isDaySpecial", ascending: false)])
```

Ascending must be `false` to have true results first. You can add another SortDescriptor to the array if you need to sort by another property after the first sort.

You can also attach the SortDescriptor array to your fetch request to get a sorted array back.